# can i check on declare cursor?

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I have 2 procedures

```
create procedure....

declare cursor c1 for 
select * from tab1 ..
```

second proc

```
create procedure ...
create table tab1 (...)
```

the first procedure wont create because the table is missing. I cannot change the order or the prc running (long explanation). so I want to compile the first procedure even if the table reading from the cursor doesnt exists.

can i do that ?

edit :

```
if  exists (select 1 from sysobjects s where s.name ='tab1' )
begin
declare IDNT_CRSR cursor for
SELECT 1 FROM tab1
end
```

Comment: why cant you just create the table on the fly?

Comment: its the very bad idea to create table on the fly....

Comment: Compiling is not a problem but you can't run this script and create the stored proc. You can check for table existence and create cursor only if table exists

Comment: @Vecchiasignora ofcourse i am handling the issue in the procedure in different

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya how ? check my edit for how i check it

Comment: Yes... That's what I mean... Is it not working?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya nop it didnt

Answer (score 0):

You should use dynamic `sql execution` and `all_objects` table, like this

```
Declare
lc_cursor sys_refcursor;
Begin
    For C in (select * 
    from all_objects 
    where object_type='TABLE' 
    and object_name = 'tab1') loop

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Begin open :usingcursor for Select 1 FROM tab1; end;'
    USING IN OUT lc_cursor;

    End loop;
End;
```

And you wont have any problem with compilation , because there is a `string` and `dynamic execution`